# C# Inheritence HW Assignment; Single Class for multiple parents?

Tags: c#

This is for a HW assignment, so it shouldn't be very difficult. In any case, we are supposed to create a base class of a Weapon and then child classes of MeleeWeapon ,Spell, Projectile, each with additional weapon attributes. That part is not so difficult. I am getting stuck with the following:

"Create a class that represents a Player with a Name and a Weapon"

I can manage creating a player class, but I'm not sure how to account for the weapon.

Do I have three different player classes such as public class Player : Spell: Weapon or public class Player: MeleeWeapon : Weapon? I feel like there should be a way to have one player class, but I'm getting flustered with how to do that. The player class also needs a constructor; again this isn't too hard, but I don't know how to account for the choices in weapon type unless I have more than one player class.

Basically, it seems like I want to have one grand child class (Player) -> three possible child classes (MeleeWeapon, Spell, Projectile) -> one parent class (Weapon), but I'm confusing myself here.

Comment: The beauty of object-oriented programming is that you *can* have one player class and multiple types of weapons ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're *entirely* mis-reading the requirement.  Take a closer look:

> Create a class that represents a Player with a Name and a Weapon

It's not saying that a Player ***is*** a Name and a Weapon, it's saying that a Player ***has*** a Name and a Weapon.

The `Player` class should have two properties: `Name` and `Weapon`.  This has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: Well, it could have a little to do with inheritance. The point may be to show that the Player can have a Weapon, but the specific type of Weapon is abstracted via inheritance. If I said that right...

Comment: @JamesR.: Other parts of the assignment might, but this specific part doesn't.  Sure, the `Weapon` property may be of the base type for weapons, which is a demonstration of polymorphism (not necessarily inheritance, though that's what's being used here).

Comment: yes that's better than how I said it. But can you really say it demonstrates polymorphism unless we know there are overridden virtual or abstract members involved? Not that it's important. Your answer is more than sufficient.

Comment: @JamesR.: Polymorphism doesn't necessarily *require* overridden or abstract members.  Two classes could be otherwise *identical* but simply referenced by different semantics in an overall inheritance structure.  (In the classic inheritance example of animals, you might have a concrete class which adds/overrides *zero* members because its parent class already defines everything which describes it.  But the class still exists because semantically that animal exists.)

Answer (score 1):

You are confused. Take a step back and follow the instructions:

> Create a class that represents a Player...

```
public class Player {}
```

> ...with a Name...

```
public class Player 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

> ...and a Weapon.

```
public class Player 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Weapon EquippedWeapon { get; set; }
}
```

You can now create different players with different weapons:

```
var alice = new Player { Name = "Alice", EquippedWeapon = new MeleeWeapon() };
var bob = new Player { Name = "Bob", EquippedWeapon = new Spell() };
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment asks you to use a **has-a** relationship between player and weapon instead of **is-a**

So in your Player class you will have

```
class Player
{
    public string Name {get; protected set;}
    public Weapon CurrentWeapon {get; protected set;}
}
```